# Loop Counter Does Not Increment Properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I seem to be having a problem with my foreach loops. I am trying to insert records into database tables using foreach loops, but it is not working correctly. Instead of 3 records being added to each table, 1 record is being added to each table. Also, each record that is being added into each table, should all be in the 1st table.

Here is the data from the tableinfo database table I am using to create the tables.

```
displayname             dbname                   category    distance     distance_id
Male 40 to 49 10KM      M40_Male40to4910KM       M40         10KM         3
Male 40 to 49 21KM      M40_Male40to4921KM       M40         21KM         2
Male 40 to 49 42KM      M40_Male40to4942KM       M40         42KM         1
```

And here is the code I am trying to get to work:

```
$tabledata = $this->db->get('tableinfo');

$i = 0;
$_temp = array();
foreach($tabledata->result() as $row) {
    $data[$i] = $this->callAPI("lateststandings&records=3&category=" . $row->category . "&distance=" . $row->distance_id);
    array_push($_temp, $row->dbname);
    $i++;
}

$j = 0;
foreach($data[$j]['Records']['Record'] as $record) {
    $record['FirstName'] .= " " . $record['LastName'];
    $this->db->replace($_temp[$j], $record);
    $j++;
}
```

I am sure the problem I am having is with the $i and $j counter variables but I am not sure where I am going wrong. It seems that the counter variables do not increment correctly.

Comment: What about to remove counters and make it like this? `$data[$i] => $data[]` 
PHP will automatically assign keys for your array so you done have to think about it.
And in second foreach split it in 2 parts 
`foreach($data as $arr)`
and inside `foreach($arr['Records'] as $record)`

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. So IF I understand correctly, would I do this:  $data[$i] => $data[] =  $this->callAPI("lateststandings&records=3&category=" . $row->category . "&distance=" . $row->distance_id);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets try to do it in this way

```
$tabledata = $this->db->get('tableinfo');
$data = [];

$_temp = array();
foreach($tabledata->result() as $row) {
    $data[] = $this->callAPI("lateststandings&records=3&category=" . $row->category . "&distance=" . $row->distance_id);
    array_push($_temp, $row->dbname);
}

foreach($data as $key => $arr) {
    foreach ($arr['Records'] as $record)
    {
        $record['FirstName'] .= " " . $record['LastName'];
        $this->db->replace($_temp[$key], $record);
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect!!!! Thank you so much for the help, you have no idea how long I have been struggling with this! Thank you!